# Reference for classification of space forms

Tags: reference-request, differential-geometry

The classification theorem aout space forms tells us, that every simply-connected, complete manifold of constant sectional curvature is isometric to a sphere, flat space or hyperbolic space.

> Can you tell about an online reference, where I can find a proof of this result?

Every help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a proof [here](http://idv.sinica.edu.tw/ftliang/diff_geom/%2adiff_geometry%28I%29/12.18/constcurvature.pdf) and then [here](http://idv.sinica.edu.tw/ftliang/diff_geom/%2adiff_geometry%28I%29/97.01.08/constcurvature2.pdf).